# How to write Test with diffrence module ? i got initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: ios, swift

I have Module A and Module B .  My test class written in A . and imported B as @testable import B. 
Everything is ok till i got this warning

'Models.SetLanguage.Response' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

The struct of Models , SetLanguage ,Response each defined as public

I hade no idea why i cant access B public module struct from module A test class.

```
public struct  Models {

   public struct SetLanguage {
    /// Data struct sent to Interactor
    public struct Request {
      let language: Language
    }
    /// Data struct sent to Presenter
    public struct Response {
      let result: Result<Language>
    }
    /// Data struct sent to ViewController
    public struct ViewModel {
      let content: Content<Language>
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `open` instead of `public`

**Code:**

```
open struct  Models {    
   open struct SetLanguage {
    public struct Request {
      let language: Language
    }
    open struct Response {
      let result: Result<Language>
    }
    open struct ViewModel {
      let content: Content<Language>
    }
  }
```